# Google Earth Api - programmatically enter StreetView mode

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-plugin, google-street-view

I'm trying to give google earth api  a start point which I get back from
Google map Api v3(I have lat and lng). The thing I want to do is give a location to
Google Earth and it can automatically moved to street view level.

So far what I did can only move to ground level. 
The following code is how I try move Google Earth's camera

```
var lookAt = DS_ge.createLookAt('');
lookAt.setLatitude(myRoute.steps[0].path[0].lat());
lookAt.setLongitude(myRoute.steps[0].path[0].lng());
lookAt.setRange(1000.0); //default is 0.0
DS_ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
```

Is there any way to achieve the result like I move the pegman to the location I want and show the street view.
I think there's a pegman function make it work but I can't find it.
Any suggestion will be helpful thx :)

Answer (score 3):

To programmatically enter StreetView mode you need to add a *gx:ViewOptions* element to the LookAt element:

```
var lookAt = ge.createLookAt('');
// ... set your LookAt parameters
// don't forget default Altitude mode is ClampToGround
lookAt.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND)

// enable Street view option on ViewerOptions and add that to LookAt
var viewerOptions = ge.createViewerOptions('');
viewerOptions.setOption(ge.OPTION_STREET_VIEW, ge.OPTION_STATE_ENABLED);
lookAt.setViewerOptions(viewerOptions);

ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
```

To control whether the user can enter Street View using manual navigation controls, call

```
var navcontrol = ge.getNavigationControl();
navcontrol.setStreetViewEnabled(true);
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_plugin#ac5c3007e6ca69cec000d2bbfa18b95c8

Comment: That is why I love stackoverflow! Thanks!

Comment: @jasonM1, How do I go about if I want to set the default street view view to main road. When it goes into street view, the camera is always looking at the ground.