# google earth moving in street mode

Tags: javascript, c++, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, google-street-view

I want to control moving in street mode by my code. But I don't know how
I am able to enter street mode and leave it. I am able to set longitude/latitude/etc, but then i change these values manually google earth's behavior is terrible. Native controls of google earth works nice (smoothly and correct moving). But i can't make something like it by programmatically.

Searching in google doesn't helps me

Is there way out? (by COM api or by javascript)
PS Sorry for my writing mistakes. English in not my native language.
PPS I have read this [Google earth api javascript control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243204/google-earth-api-javascript-control) but it was 2 years ago

EDIT:
I've had read this post [Google Earth Api - programmatically enter StreetView mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634742/google-earth-api-programmatically-enter-streetview-mode) but it doesn't contain information about programmatic way to moving in street view
I've answered for comment with this post [google earth moving in street mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144330/google-earth-moving-in-street-mode#comment26581131_18144330) and explained why it don't satisfy me

Comment: +1 for title - sounds like an earthquake.

Comment: @MartinJames camera rotation (heading/azimuth and tilt) and "range" changes works in some cases (javascript api, not COM), but it happens very rarely

Comment: Check out a related question to programmatically enter StreetView mode via JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634742/google-earth-street-view-layer-how-pegman-working

Comment: @JasonM1 I use it for enter street view but i found no info about moving in street view.

Comment: For moderators: see edit please